# asp.net get date from yyMMdd

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this small code here:

```
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
{
    var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
        @isoDate
    </div>
}
```

That will print out all the dates in my view that i missed, and like you can see it prints out them like "yymmdd yymmdd yymmdd" etc, but it's hard to know what weekday it is, so I would like to be "mo yymmdd tu yymmdd we yymmdd" so it's the two first letters of the day, how can I achive this?

Comment: Side note: Your format does not follow ISO8601, so please don't name fields in such deceiving way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be using the format "ddd yyMMdd" instead.
It will print the first 3 letters on the week day, instead of of just 2. But I think there is no standard format just for two letters.

If you really need just 2 letter, you can substring the original "ddd" format:

```
@date.ToString("ddd").Substring(0, 2)
```

Comment: Things are always easier than I seem to make them.

Comment: Please be aware that `"ddd"` may create strings longer or shorter than 3 letters in other languages and clipping it to 2 letters could possibly be ambiguous in some language.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to keep the `value` part as it is - or ideally as `yyyyMMdd`, as two-digit year formats are horrible - and just format the *display* part differently. I don't think there's anything to use two-letter month abbreviations - the abbreviated month names are in English cultures are normally three letters rather than two. (This varies by culture. I don't know of any English-based cultures which use two letters, but some other cultures do, such as German.)

I'd actually recommend using just the `d` [standard date format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) for display, or possibly `D` (long rather than short) as that will then use an appropriate format for the culture - assuming the current thread's culture has been set appropriately. So something like:

```
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
{
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate"
               name="isoDate"
               value="@date.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)" />
        @date.ToString("D")
    </div>
}
```

(The razor syntax may be  slightly off - hopefully you'll be able to adapt it accordingly.)

I know you've said what you want the format to be, but I suspect you're thinking solely about users in your own culture. Do you know whether that format will be appropriate in other cultures? If all your users are guaranteed to be English, that's not such a problem - but in general you should avoid such assumptions.

Comment: "the abbreviated month names are normally three letters rather than two": This is not true for all languages; in German for example it is two letters.

Comment: I did try a simular solution first, but that did end up like like displaying 4t may 2015. I just want it to say "Mo yymdd Tu yymmdd We yymmdd" the first two letters of the weekday.

Comment: @Sebastian: Right. I suspected that might be the case, hence "normally" rather than "always" - but I'll reword later, when I get a chance.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but English is not more "normal" than any other language ;)

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus: Well, if *most* cultures use three letters, I think that makes it the "normal" case. I've edited though - hope this is clearer.

Comment: @foobar: Yes, I know what you want - but I'm saying that you're making an assumption about what format is useful which may well not be valid for all your users. (I would personally *hate* to see a format using "yy"... and I don't expect a year-first format is friendly to many users.) Then there's the matter of whether the first two letters even uniquely identify the day of week. If you're in the unusual situation where you *only* care about English cultures, it would be worth stating that in the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, your solution would be the best it's easy to understand which date it is. But I were told to have it like that, and I am just doing what I am told.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I agree your point. But we can achieve this in different way. What do you think about my solution?

Comment: @codeninja: Yes, that would work if you only care about English. .

Comment: @foobar: That's not the same as "I would like" in your question. I would at least point out the drawbacks of this to whoever has told you to do this...

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, I am sorry for that. Next time I ask something i'll look through it a third time. I did have it setup so it did show 2015-08-19 but they wanted it just to be mo150809

Answer (score 0):

> var isoDate = date.ToString("dddd yyMMdd");

This will solve your problem.

```
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
{


var isoDate = date.ToString("dddd yyMMdd");

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
        @isoDate
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, `AbbreviatedDayNames` contains three letter days ("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", and "Sat")

To get custom day name, you are allowed to assign your custom day names array to `AbbreviatedDayNames`

```
@{   
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("");
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtinfo = ci.DateTimeFormat;
dtinfo.AbbreviatedDayNames = new string[] { "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa" };
 }
```

`ddd` is the format specifier of `AbbreviatedDayNames` so you should use `ddd` to get your custom day name

```
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
{
 var isoDate = date.ToString("{ddd yyMMdd}", dtinfo);
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
    @isoDate
</div>
}
```

--SJ